# How can I change the password for pgadmin in Windows?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to know how I can change the password of pgAdmin, the same one that is created when it is installed in Windows

The point is that I have not forgotten, but for personal reasons I want to change the password.
I repeat, I know the password so what I'm looking for is just trying to change it

I am using version 12.4 on Windows 10